# oracle get all matched occurrences from a column

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I have a table, which has 2 columns: ID & JOB_Description(Text).
I would like to write an oracle SQL to extract all substrings in the
Description column which match a regular pattern.

However, I have learnt how to extract matched substrings from a string with below SQL, but I have no idea to apply below SQL on all data in one go on the aforementioned table(column:JOB_Description).

SQL to get all matched occurrences from a string:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(JOB_Description, '(ABC|DE)([[:digit:]]){5}', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
   FROM (
         select 'Please help to repair ABC12345, DE22222' as JOB_Description 
          from DUAL)
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(JOB_Description, '(ABC|DE)([[:digit:]]){5}');
```

Comment: just replace the string in the inner query with the column name.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala that won't do in this case because of CONNECT BY

Comment: Do you have an additional column which is unique? Or is job description unique?

Comment: ID is unique ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this query out.

```
 with test as(
  select 'ABC12345, DE22222' as JOB_Description from DUAL union
  select 'Please help to repair ABC12345, DE22222' as JOB_Description from DUAL 
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(JOB_Description, '(ABC|DE)([[:digit:]]){5}', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
FROM test
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(JOB_Description, '(ABC|DE)([[:digit:]]){5}')
  AND PRIOR JOB_Description = JOB_Description
  AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
```

**Result:**

```
ABC12345
DE22222
ABC12345
DE22222
```

A good explanation of the last two lines can be found [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: JOB_Description = JOB_Description?

Comment: @MemoryLeak I've added a link with an already detailed answer