# SQL performance optimization

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle11g, query-performance

I got following two SQLs which return the same result,I was expecting SQL2 was going to be faster than SQL1, but it turns out that SQL1 was 5 times faster than SQL2. Could someone explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

```
SQL1: 2 seconds
select count(*) from (
select * from (
SELECT distinct job_id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(JOB_Description, '(ABC|CDE)([[:digit:]]){5}', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
FROM (
    select  job_id, JOB_DESCRIPTION from smms.job where TO_NUMBER(to_char(CREATE_DATE,'YYYY'))=2017
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(JOB_Description, '(ABC|CDE)([[:digit:]]){5}')
and prior job_description = job_description
AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT null
order by job_id
) **where substr is not null**);

SQL2: 11 seconds
select count(*) from (
SELECT distinct job_id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(JOB_Description, '(ABC|CDE)([[:digit:]]){5}', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
FROM (
    select  job_id, JOB_DESCRIPTION from smms.job where TO_NUMBER(to_char(CREATE_DATE,'YYYY'))=2017 **and  REGEXP_COUNT(JOB_Description, '(ABC|CDE)([[:digit:]]){5}')>0**
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(JOB_Description, '(ABC|CDE)([[:digit:]]){5}')
and prior job_description = job_description
AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT null
order by job_id
);
```

Comment: . . With your reputation, you should be able to format your question.

Comment: Are you using Oracle?  I think that should be the very first tag you use, rather than the other ones.

Comment: I am using a mobile phone browser which doesn't have such function, sorry, I will try.

Comment: Yes I am using Oracle, I haven't written SQL for a long time~

Comment: Thank @dnoeth for the help!

Comment: YourJOIN/CONNECT conditions don't look very sargable to me. And the ORDER BY in the second query is useless.

Comment: They both have ORDER BY

Comment: @MemoryLeak I don't see point of so many nested queries. I would try single level `SELECT COUNT(distinct job_id || '^' ||  REGEXP_SUBSTR(JOB_Description, '(ABC|CDE)([[:digit:]]){5}', 1, LEVEL) 
FROM from smms.job
WHERE CREATE_DATE >= DATE '2017-01-01' AND CREATE_DATE < '2018-01-01'
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(JOB_Description, '(ABC|CDE)([[:digit:]]){5}')
  and prior job_description = job_description
  AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT null`

Comment: Avoid using `CONNECT BY`, `PRIOR`, etc. It's been almost deprecated now. I'm sure it still works but you should move to CTEs that offer you much more flexibility.

Comment: Please refer to my another question for the reason I use connect BY:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002738/oracle-get-all-matched-occurrences-from-a-column/52002900?noredirect=1#comment90958521_52002900